# Can I set Gmail to always display images from a domain?

Tags: gmail, images

The emails that come from Twitter always come from a seemingly random email address (probably some kind of hash) like `mention-fpbgg.ivivna+cxza=tznvy.pbz-b2b51@postmaster.twitter.com`

If I click "Always display messages from" it only works for that specific email address. Is it possible to add a wildcard address from which to display images? e.g. everything from `@postmaster.twitter.com`

Comment: Seems it is not possible: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=079bb26565786abf&hl=en

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This isn't possible. For the following reasons:

- There isn't a way to setup a filter to show images for certain conditions
- There is no way to see the list of senders you've allowed to display images (which means you can't edit it)
- You can't assign a label that displays images always within it.

I've wanted this feature as well because it's annoying to have to click it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Use an email client like Windows Essentials Mail, Outlook or Mac OS X Mail to access your Gmail via IMAP. These clients have the option you're looking for.